# How to make a link that is not the focus looked faded?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have two html forms that are combined into one view and can be selected through tabs (I'm using bootstrap panel-tabs to accomplish this). I was wondering how to via css if possible make the inactive tab link look faded and then when you click on it and it becomes the focus the other tab becomes faded.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 form card z-depth-3">
    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active find-pad-border"><a href="#findPartTitle" data-toggle="tab" class="find-tab"><h4>Find a participant</h4></a></li>
                <li class="find-pad"><a href="#findTeamTitle" data-toggle="tab" class="find-tab"><h4>Search for a team</h4></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="findPartTitle">
                    <div>
                        <form id="findFriendForm" name="findFriendForm" action="http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR" method="post" novalidate>
                            <input type="hidden" name="s_tr_part_finder_search_mode" id="s_tr_part_finder_search_mode" value="basic">
                            <input type="hidden" name="fr_search_type" id="fr_search_type" value="participant">
                            <input type="hidden" id="fr_id_participant" name="fr_id" value="[[S334:fr_id]]">
                            <input type="hidden" id="pg" name="pg" value="pfind">
                            <input type="hidden" id="submit" name="submit" value="true">
                            <i>First Name</i>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" size="20" name="searchFirstName" id="searchFirstName" maxlength="50">
                            <br />
                            <i>Last Name</i>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" size="20" name="searchLastName" id="searchLastName" maxlength="50">
                            <br />
                            <button class="btn btn-yellow" id="fr_find_search" name="fr_find_search" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="findTeamTitle">
                    <div>
                        <form id="teamFindFriendForm" name="findFriendForm" action="http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR" method="post" novalidate>
                            <input type="hidden" name="s_tr_part_finder_search_mode" id="s_tr_part_finder_search_mode_team" value="basic">
                            <input type="hidden" name="fr_search_type" id="fr_search_type_team" value="team" size="" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="fr_id_team" name="fr_id" value="[[S334:fr_id]]" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="teamPg" name="pg" value="pfind" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="teamSubmit" name="submit" value="true" />
                            <i>Team Name</i>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" size="20" name="searchTeam" id="teamSearchTeam" maxLength="50">
                            <br />
                            <button class="btn btn-yellow" id="fr_find_search_team" name="fr_find_search" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel.with-nav-tabs .panel-heading {
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-justified {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.find-tab {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

li.find-pad-border {
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: solid 1px #eeeeee;
}

li.find-pad-border:hover {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

li.find-pad{
    padding: 5px;
}

li.find-pad:hover {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

li.find-pad:inactive {

}
```

I thought maybe `:inactive` was a real thing, turns out it's not lol. I've added a screen shot so you know what the search form looks like.

[image: form-search]

Hoping someone can give me some direction. Please let me know if there are additional information you need that I have over looked!

Thanks!

Comment: Give the two panels different classes and then choose the sibling with the sibling operator when one tab is active, you can set active state with a toggling class and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `active` class must be applied to the link (not the `li`):

```
<li class="find-pad-border">
    <a href="#findPartTitle" data-toggle="tab" class="active find-tab">
      <h4>Find a participant</h4>
   </a>
</li>
```

Then you need to set the appropriate CSS declarations

```
.nav-tabs h4 {
  color: #666;
}

.nav-tabs .active h4 {
  color: #66f;
}
```

Working demo

```css
.nav-tabs h4 {
  color: #666;
}

.nav-tabs .active h4 {
  color: #66f;
}



.panel.with-nav-tabs .panel-heading {
  padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-justified {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.find-tab {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

li.find-pad-border {
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: solid 1px #eeeeee;
}

li.find-pad-border:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

li.find-pad {
  padding: 5px;
}

li.find-pad:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

li.find-pad:inactive {}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 form card z-depth-3">
  <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="find-pad-border">
          <a href="#findPartTitle" data-toggle="tab" class="active find-tab">
            <h4>Find a participant</h4>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="find-pad">
          <a href="#findTeamTitle" data-toggle="tab" class="find-tab">
            <h4>Search for a team</h4>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="findPartTitle">
          <div>
            <form id="findFriendForm" name="findFriendForm" action="http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR" method="post" novalidate>
              <input type="hidden" name="s_tr_part_finder_search_mode" id="s_tr_part_finder_search_mode" value="basic">
              <input type="hidden" name="fr_search_type" id="fr_search_type" value="participant">
              <input type="hidden" id="fr_id_participant" name="fr_id" value="[[S334:fr_id]]">
              <input type="hidden" id="pg" name="pg" value="pfind">
              <input type="hidden" id="submit" name="submit" value="true">
              <i>First Name</i>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" size="20" name="searchFirstName" id="searchFirstName" maxlength="50">
              <br />
              <i>Last Name</i>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" size="20" name="searchLastName" id="searchLastName" maxlength="50">
              <br />
              <button class="btn btn-yellow" id="fr_find_search" name="fr_find_search" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="findTeamTitle">
          <div>
            <form id="teamFindFriendForm" name="findFriendForm" action="http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR" method="post" novalidate>
              <input type="hidden" name="s_tr_part_finder_search_mode" id="s_tr_part_finder_search_mode_team" value="basic">
              <input type="hidden" name="fr_search_type" id="fr_search_type_team" value="team" size="" />
              <input type="hidden" id="fr_id_team" name="fr_id" value="[[S334:fr_id]]" />
              <input type="hidden" id="teamPg" name="pg" value="pfind" />
              <input type="hidden" id="teamSubmit" name="submit" value="true" />
              <i>Team Name</i>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" size="20" name="searchTeam" id="teamSearchTeam" maxLength="50">
              <br />
              <button class="btn btn-yellow" id="fr_find_search_team" name="fr_find_search" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! just one question, why does the active class need to be on the anchor link instead of the li? does it behave differently?

Comment: That's how bootstrap works, it will update the class only in the link when you switch between tabs.

Comment: oh I didn't know that. Thank you Sabastien! sorry for the late reply. but you've saved me a ton of headache!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use :not(.active) css

```
.nav-tabs li:not(.active) a{
   opacity:0.3
}

.nav-tabs li.active a{
   opacity:1
}
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RyPqxb

Comment: oh wow I had no idea there was a `:not` function. This is cool thank you!